# Draper - NoMethodError with RSpec testing for decorator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, draper

I'm receiving the following error when trying to test with [Draper](https://github.com/jcasimir/draper):

```
NoMethodError: undefined method 'with_unit' for nil:NilClass
```

Here's my test code:

```
# spec/decorators/food_decorator_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe FoodDecorator do
  before { ApplicationController.new.set_current_view_context }
  FactoryGirl.create(:food)
  @food = FoodDecorator.first

  specify { @food.with_unit('water').should == "85.56 g" }
end
```

And here's my decorator code:

```
class FoodDecorator < ApplicationDecorator
  decorates :food

  def with_unit(nutrient)
    model.send(nutrient.to_sym).to_s + " g"
  end
end
```

My research suggests that the line `ApplicationController.new.set_current_view_context` should fix this, but it hasn't. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace with:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe FoodDecorator do
  before do
    ApplicationController.new.set_current_view_context
    FactoryGirl.create(:food)
    @food = FoodDecorator.first
  end

  specify { @food.with_unit('water').should == "85.56 g" }
end
```

You could even do:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe FoodDecorator do

  let(:food) { Factory(:food) }
  subject { FoodDecorator.first }

  before do
    food
    ApplicationController.new.set_current_view_context
  end

  specify { subject.with_unit('water').should == "85.56 g" }
end
```

Comment: That did work, but can you explain where I went wrong? Thanks :)

Comment: your factory wasn't included in your before block, simply :)

Comment: I'm getting an issue with the second code block at the `subject { FoodDecorator.first }` line where the `FactoryGirl.create` line has not yet been run. I suspect this is due to memoizing with the `let` statement. Since the factory has not been run, `FoodDecorator.first` returns `nil`. Removing the `let` portion and leaving it only as `FactoryGirl.create(:food)` fixes this issue. Any thoughts on ways to solve this or if my current solution is acceptable?